# Datos no devueltos desde un WCFDS

Tags: html, .net

Trato de obtener información desde mi base de datos con un WCF DataServices pero cuando lo invoco obtengo el siguiente error:

> Recurso no encontrado para el segmento 'GetCustomers'.

¿Qué podrá ser?

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior( IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]
    public class WcfDataService1 : DataService< Modelitos.NorthwindEntities /* TODO: put your data source class name here */ >
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
            // Examples:
             config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Customers", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
             config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        }


        public List<Modelitos.Customers> GetCustomers()
        {
            return
                this.CurrentDataSource.Customers.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Como estas invocando el servicio ? lo realizas con jquery con el $.ajax. Intentaste invocar el servicio con alguna tool como ser fiddler o postman ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mas seguro es que no has "decorado" tu método usa el [WebGet] antes de publicar tu método:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior( IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]
    public class WcfDataService1 : DataService< Modelitos.NorthwindEntities /* TODO: put your data source class name here */ >
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
            // Examples:
             config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Customers", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
             config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        }

        [WebGet] // TE FALTA ESTO
        public List<Modelitos.Customers> GetCustomers()
        {
            return
                this.CurrentDataSource.Customers.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pues si me esta corriendo JOJO